# How can I remove authentication for TeamCity (public site)?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

How can I make my TeamCity site be a public site. I don't want the landing page when someone goes to my TeamCity site to be the login page but instead just the Overview page that lists out all of the projects.

Making everyone login as a guest from the login page seems like a worthless step that I'd rather them not have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical way I can think of doing this *currently* is by providing the guest login as a direct link. For example, Castle Windsor allows the guest login and you can go directly there by browsing to:

> http://builds.castleproject.org/guestLogin.html?guest=1

this is different from browsing to

> http://builds.castleproject.org/

which takes you to the login page.